# Why the Required property of field is changing to false?

Tags: list, content-type, wss-3.0, column, properties

I created site column with `Required="true"`. Then I created site content type and added my column to it . Then I created list, selected "Allow management of content types?" to "Yes" and added my content type.

So my question is - why Required property of the field becomes "false" after editing field's properties through "List->Settings->Field"? It is reproducible when content type "Item" is turned off or deleted or not default in the list.